# Ubuntu wont recognize my internal SSD

Tags: boot, 12.10, hard-drive, lenovo, bios

I just bought a Lenovo u310 and installed Ubuntu 12.10 with Wubi to try it out. After a couple of days I decided to fully replace windows 7 and installed Ubuntu 12.10 fully with a usb drive in my HDD. After installation I can't find my internal SSD, which I did not touch at any point. When I open the BIOS menu, in the boot priority order I can see the ATA SSD1. Any help on whats wrong?

Edit: Extra info asked for

```
sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1   976773167   488386583+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

sudo blkid

/dev/sda1: UUID="0A0D-5756" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="f7e010ad-3fb1-44fc-bcba-0e0be3b3fdbd" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="8014eddb-855e-44cf-b3d9-97421cb6be25" TYPE="swap"
```

Comment: We'd only be guessing based on the description, but it's probably right where you left it.  We need more information - please add the output of the following terminal commands to your question: "sudo blkid" and "sudo fdisk -l"

Comment: BTW, the SSD is normally faster, so people tend to prefer to put the / filesystem and the swap partititon on the SSD so it boots and resumes from hibernation faster, and mount the hard drive as /home so that there's plenty of space for data.